# How to automate copying bulk pdf files from one Share point folder to another in Windows

Tags: windows

I wonder if someone has ideas to my case.
I have a list of >200 pdf file names of documents that are saved in a share point folder and I need to copy them to another share point folder. I have looked at video clips of how to use Power Automate to copy/move files, which is very good when the file data type is used as the criteria for selecting the files. However, my list is in word and want to find a way of reading the file names, search them in the source folder and copy to the destination folder.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider to share the link to the 2nd SharePoint folder inside the 1st SharePoint folder to avoid copying at all?

That been said, you can load your word file into a list in Power Automate and then loop through the list (assuming your word doc has the complete path & filename line by line)

Some references:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/how-to/extract-text-word-document

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/use-loops

The rest should be as in the video clips.